# What's more "expensive": Creating a too big ArrayList or upsizing an ArrayList?

Tags: java, performance, collections, arraylist

I've got an existing `ArrayList` which will be filtered according to certain criteria. I'm using Apache's `CollectionUtils.select(Collection, Predicate, Collection)` for filtering.

The second collection which is passed to this method will be populated with the relevant objects. Is it now more wise to create this new collection with

```
List newList = new ArrayList();
```

or with

```
List newList = new ArrayList(listToBeFiltered.size());
```

?

In the first case, the `List` will be upsized if the initial capacity is reached, while in the second case sometimes a way too big `List` will be created.

Which way is the better one? And please correct me if I've made any mistakes in my explanation.

Comment: The answer is: it depends.

Comment: It depends but it probibly doesn't make any difference.  Does this show up as significant in the memory profile for your application?

Comment: How big is the original list? How big do you expect the filtered list to be?

Comment: @assylias How do you define expensive? (Memory/time) How long does the predicate take to run? The list of questions goes on.

Comment: Actually I've asked the question more or less out of curiosity. I don't think that this operation will ever be a bottleneck.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

That normally depends on the final size and the size of the collection to be filtered.

Resizing an `ArrayList` or normally done by doubling the current size and copying the content around. Thus with a huge final size there might be couple of resize operations needed.

On the other hand a really large initial size might eat up quite a lot of memory and might trigger garbage collection earler, but the list would have to be *really* big.

You might try and profile both options but for standard sizes I'd prefer specifying a sensible initial size.

Answer (score 1):

If you have any intuition on the selectivity of your filtering then you could size the list slightly larger than its expected size. If the selectivity is typically 20% then you could set the final result to (say) 25%.

```
 List newList = new ArrayList((int) (0.25 * listToBeFiltered.size()));
```

Answer (score 0):

In most cases, the 'upsizing' will be more expensive as it incurs a penalty each time it needs to make more room. For adding lots of entries, this will result in tiny delays during execution. Allocating a large size to begin with only incurs that penalty once, assuming you don't later add more items. Note, however, that dynamic arrays / lists / containers generally have a granularity that gives a reasonable capacity before they have to re-allocate memory, so for a small number of items you might not spot any difference.

Answer (score 0):

Depends, you have a chance of wasting some space on both.

But by intuition if you think resulting array will be much smaller than input, I suggest you use List newList = new ArrayList();

Initial capacity for Arraylist is 10 and size doubles if it is full.